# Python win32com.client for Outlook : 'Move' function move limited number of emails from inbox to other folder

Tags: python-3.x, email, outlook, move, win32com

**Context :** I have 100 emails with the a subject as `'Target subject <something>'` in my Oulook inbox and I want to move them all in an other folder, let's say `'MyFolder'`. Here is my python (version=3.9.6) program :

```py
import win32com.client

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
root_folder = outlook.Folders.Item(1)

inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
myfolder = root_folder.Folders['MyFolder']
messages = inbox.Items

for message in messages:
    if 'Target subject' in message.Subject:
        message.Move(myfolder)
```

**Problem:** The program runs without throwing any error but only 20 emails of 100 expected are moved. If I run the program several times, it achieved to move all like 20 at a time.

**Attempts:**  I've searched in [windows API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._mailitem.move?view=outlook-pia#Microsoft_Office_Interop_Outlook__MailItem_Move_Microsoft_Office_Interop_Outlook_MAPIFolder_) but found nothing useful.

**Question :** Any idea of what's causing this limitation and how to avoid it?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I have noticed the following lines of code:

```
for message in messages:
    if 'Target subject' in message.Subject:
```

That is really not a good idea to iterate over all items in the folder and check  whether a subject line contains specific keywords. Instead, I'd recommend using the [Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869662.aspx)/[FindNext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff862482.aspx) or [Restrict](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869597.aspx) methods of the `Items` class. Read more about these methods in the following articles:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

If you still deal with a collection of items (in the case of `Restrict` method) you need to iterate through all items using the `for` loop from the end and call the `Move` method in the following way:

```
for i in reversed(messages):
    i.Move(myFolder)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for ressources ! It's my first attemp with windows API and the documentation isn't easy to use.  I'll read it and post a solution later.

Comment: I've read the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.Items.Restrict) it says : "There is no way to perform a "contains" operation [...]. Instead, you can use the `AdvancedSearch method`, or you can loop through all of the items in the folder and use the InStr function to perform a search within a field. " I couldn't achieve to make AdvancedSearch work. It throws a `com_error : 'Incorrect parameter` so I guess I will have to do the loop solution.

Comment: I wrote the code like : `search = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").AdvancedSearch(inbox)`

Comment: See [Advanced search in Outlook programmatically: C#, VB.NET](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2012/05/31/outlook-search-csharp-vbnet/) how to use `AdvancedSearch` in the code.

Answer (score 1):

You are looping over the collection while changing it (by moving messages) - it is inevitable you will end up with skipped items.

You need a reverse loop from Count down to 1.

Comment: Thanks for the tips ! I'll post a solution later.